# Interpreting negative difference in mean?

Tags: mean, interpretation, meta-analysis

I'm currently doing a meta-analysis, looking at risk factors for the development of a disease. Most of my data has been converted to odds ratios, which I have no difficulty interpreting. However, in 10 of my studies the mean age ± SD was given between the cases and controls. The summary difference in means was given as:

-1.47 [-2.20, -0.74]

The cases were younger than the controls, on average, so I understand the reason for the negative value and also that it is statistically significant because the 95% CI doesn't cross zero.

With OR, I know that anything above 1 indicates increased likelihood for disease development, however, I'm not entirely sure how I should be interpreting the difference in means (or is there nothing to interpret and I'm being a bit dim)?

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to me to be an interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So I shouldn't be looking at it like an OR/RR where a value below the line of effect means that disease development is less likely, because of the type of data it is, I should just describe what I see? Sorry if that seems like a dumb question, doing this for my postgrad but haven't done stats since my undergrad 10 years ago!